# cannot safe dictionary into variable

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I am using [SQLiteDB](https://github.com/FahimF/SQLiteDB) to access a SQLiteDB in a mobile application I am writing.  I am starting to write a small model class to receive the rows returned by SQLiteDB and make them easily accessible to the rest of my program.  However, when I try to start the results I get an error that I do not understand.

This is the code I am trying to run

```
import Foundation

class DBModel {
    static let db = SQLiteDB.sharedInstance()

    required init(attributeParams: [String: Any]) {
        let attrbitues = attributeParams
    }

    class func all() -> [DBModel] {
        let rawAttributes = db.query("select * from \(tableName())")
        print(self)
        var objects = [DBModel]()

        for record in rawAttributes {
            print(record)
            objects.append(self.init(attributeParams: record))
        }

        return objects

    }
}
```

When I run this code I get this error:
The error I get is: `fatal error: can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes` from this line `objects.append(self.init(attributeParams: record))`.  The output of `print(record)` is `["id": 1, "name": Josh]`.

I am very new to Swift.  But, I think it might have something to do with the fact that SQLiteDB query returns the hash with optional values.  However, I have no idea to to resolve it.

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: OK, feeling stupid here. I changed  `[String: Any]` to  `[String: AnyObject?]` and it seems to have removed their error.  However, no idea why.  If you could help me understand the difference between Any and AnyObject I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`db.query` returns `[[String:AnyObject]]`. You then iterate over that, so `record` is of type `[String:AnyObject]`. You then try to pass that to a parameter of type `[String: Any]`, but `AnyObject` is a subset of `Any`. The error is a little confusing, but is related to Swift's lack of covariance on dictionaries. `[String:Cat]` is not a subtype of `[String:Animal]`. Similarly, `[String: AnyObject]` is not a subtype of `[String: Any]`.

To your question of `Any` vs `AnyObject`, `Any` is literally any type known to Swift. `AnyObject` is only "object types." Many things aren't object types. In practice, objects are classes in Swift, though there is some surprising rule-bending if Foundation is imported. Without Foundation, Strings are not `AnyObject`. With Foundation, String is implicitly converted to `NSString` which is a class, and so is an `AnyObject`. But for the most part, you can think of `AnyObject` as "classes and class-like things."